# Why this regex for parsing m3u doesn't work?

Tags: regex

The m3u file looks like this:

#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:153741
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11
#EXTINF:**10.005333**,
**/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-58-29.ts**
#EXTINF:**9.984000**,
**/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-58-39.ts**
#EXTINF:**10.005333**,
**/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-58-49.ts**
#EXTINF:**10.005333**,
**/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-58-59.ts**
#EXTINF:**10.005333**,
**/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-59-09.ts**
#EXTINF:**9.984000**,
**/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-59-19.ts**

I would like to extract pairs in bold. e.g.:
**10.005333**
**/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-58-29.ts**

I managed to solved the problem only partially. The following regex gives me durations (numbers after the `#EXT-INF:`)

```
(?<=^EXTINF:)?(\d+\.\d+)(?=,\r|,\n)
```

But, when I try to add something to that regex at the end, something like `^(.*)` in order to capture anything beginning after the \r or \n, I get nothing. I need to capture anything in the line that follows immediately after the number that follows the #EXTINF:. Can somebody help with that?

Update:

> const char * const pm3u = 
> {
>  "#EXTM3U\n" "#EXT-X-VERSION:3\n"
>   "#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:153741\n" 
> "#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO\n"
>   "#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11\n" 
> "#EXTINF:10.005333,\n"
>   "/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-58-29.ts\n"
>   "#EXTINF:9.984000,\n"
>   "/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-58-39.ts\n"
>   "#EXTINF:10.005333,\n"
>   "/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-58-49.ts\n"
>   "#EXTINF:10.005333,\n"
>   "/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-58-59.ts\n"
>   "#EXTINF:10.005333,\n"
>   "/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-59-09.ts\n"
>   "#EXTINF:9.984000,\n"
>   "/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-59-19.ts\n"
>  };
>
> int main()
>  {
>       std::regex regExpression( "(#EXTINF:)(\\d+.\\d+)*" );
>       std::smatch regExMatch;
>       const std::string str( pm3u );
>       bool b = std::regex_match( str.begin(), str.end(), regExMatch, regExpression );
>   return 0;
>   }

Comment: Glad [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49389467/3832970) worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex can be fixed if

- You convert the lookbehind to a consuming pattern
- If you replace `^` with `(?:^|\n)` to match start of lines, not just the start of the string
- If you use an `std::sregex_iterator` to match multiple matches instead of `std::regex_match` that only matches the whole string (i.e. the pattern must match the whole string)
- If you add the `#` before `EXTINF` since your expected matches start with `#EXTINF`.

Use

```
const std::regex rx(R"((?:^|\n)#EXTINF:(\d+\.\d+),[\r\n]+(.*))");
   std::string test = "#EXTM3U\n#EXT-X-VERSION:3\n#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:153741\n#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO\n#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11\n#EXTINF:10.005333,\n/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-58-29.ts\n#EXTINF:9.984000,\n/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-58-39.ts\n#EXTINF:10.005333,\n/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-58-49.ts\n#EXTINF:10.005333,\n/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-58-59.ts\n#EXTINF:10.005333,\n/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-59-09.ts\n#EXTINF:9.984000,\n/RTS_1_009/audio/2018-03-16-H13/audio-2018-03-16-13-59-19.ts";
   for(std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(test.begin(), test.end(), rx);
                         i != std::sregex_iterator();
                         ++i)
   {
    std::smatch m = *i;
    std::cout << "Part 1:"  << m[1].str() << "\nPart 2:"  << m[2].str() << std::endl;
   }
```

The regex is

```
(?:^|\n)#EXTINF:(\d+\.\d+),[\r\n]+(.*)
```

See [this regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/b6zvf5/1).

Answer (score 0):

This regex will get you the *pairs* in capture groups 1 & 2

`EXTINF:(\d+\.\d+),\r?\n(.*)`

https://regex101.com/r/ZYGhZy/1

Comment: It doesn't work at all with STL, or with Expresso. Even on regex101 the output is not correct. regex101 is not really a reference.